# Maven not Running Tests Specified in Profile

Tags: testing, maven, selenium, profile

I've got a vary simple profile in my maven pom file to run some integration tests during the normal test phase. Note I do not want to run these tests during the normal integration-test phase because I do not want to build the war and deploy etc. The tests run fine as normal JUnit tests.

So here is my profile:

```xml
<profile>
  <id>AdminSeltests</id>
  <build>
    <plugins>
   <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.12</version>

      <configuration>
          <includes>
            <include>**/*/TestSellerSignupWizard.java</include>
          </includes>
      </configuration>

      <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>execution2</id>
        <phase>test</phase>
       </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin> 
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

My test is called:

```
com.xxxxx.xxx.client.selenium.seller_signup.TestCustomerSignupWizard
```

However when I run the above profile with:

```
mvn test -P AdminSeltests
```

No tests are run. I have tried the following as the  value(s):

```xml
<include>**/TestSellerSignupWizard.*</include>
<include>**/TestSeller*.*</include>
<include>**/TestSeller*.java</include>
<include>**/*/TestSeller*.java</include>
<include>
  com.xxxxx.xxx.client.selenium.seller_signup.TestCustomerSignupWizard.java
</include>
```

None of these work.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks 
Adam

SOLVED:
I'm using the `maven-surefire-plugin` and this has a automatic `includes` section which includes your normal test stuff. So I made an `exclude` configuration to exclude the normal unit tests, and then an `include` section to include a patter of integration test that I want to run

Not sure why it works this way, but it does:

```
<configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/Test*.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*Test.java</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*TestCase.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
    <includes>
      <include>**/ITTestSellerSignupWizard.java</include>
    </includes>
</configuration>
```

Thanks for your help everyone.

Answer (score 2):

The actual piece of code you did paste obviously doesn't work because you're mentioning class `TestSellerSignupWizard` while having tests in `TestCustomerSignupWizard`. I assume however it's a typo which doesn't matter actually because one of the Surefire's default mask for inclusion is `**/Test*.java` that fits well with you in this case.

So it all looks like working solution, so I'm afraid a problem is you don't have this class in your test classpath. You mentioned this is somehow related to integration testing so probably this class is located in `src/it/java` and not `src/test/java` that is Maven's default for Surefire. If I'm right, you should move this class into `src/test/java` or use (as you tried) alternative Surefire execution but with `testSourceDirectory` parameter overrided ([link](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html)).

Comment: You're right about the typo. The test is in target\test-classes\com\***\admin\client\selenium\seller_signup\TestSellerSignupWizard.class

So should be on the classpath. If I run 'mvn test' all works fine. :-(

Comment: Try move `<configuration>` into `<execution>`.